# in a binary features and one binary output case, is the size of a hypothesis space = $2^{\text{the size of input space}}$?

Tags: machine-learning

this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/304702/247356) gives a set of observations:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 | y
---------------
 0  0  0  1 | 0
 0  1  0  1 | 0
 1  1  0  0 | 1
 0  0  1  0 | 1
```

and claims that

> The input space is in the above given example $2^4$
>
> The hypothesis space is $2^{2^4}=65536$

may I get a formula shown below from the statement above?

in this binary features and one binary output case, the size of a hypothesis space = $2^{\text{the size of input space}}$